# Is there a version of rmver that uses "rmname" instead of "rmelem" as part of its invocation?

Tags: clearcase

## Background

I have a directory element in clearcase that has a version tree as shown below:

```
VIEW_NAME --> Version 0 --> Version 1
```

I am trying to remove `Version 1` of the directory so that the version tree looks like this:

```
VIEW_NAME --> Version 0
```

## Problem

I have tried to use [`rmver`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm) to accomplish what I want. However, I am not allowed to invoke `rmelem` at all, which `rmver` uses as part of the command. I know this because I have faced the following error:

> ERROR: User myusername cannot use rmelem. Use rmname instead.
>
> cleartool: Warning: Trigger "TRG_NO_RMELEM" has refused to let rmver proceed
>
> cleartool: Error: Unable to remove versions of ".".

## Attempted Solution

I have ran a search through the man pages of `rmver` and [`rmbranch`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmbranch.htm) for a possible option to use a `rmname` version of either command, however there is nothing in either man page. This lack of an `rmname` like functionality in either command has lead me to ask the question:

## Question

Is there a version of the `rmver` command that uses `rmname` as part of its core execution instead of `rmelem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: `rmver` would never use `rmname`.

As [mentioned here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/bs/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/c_remove_elem.htm)

> Removing an element name from its parent directory (`cleartool rmname`) does not affect the element itself, but two other types of a removal operation do irrevocably affect an element. Be very conservative when performing these operations (`rmver`, `rmelem`)

Since:

> `rmver` deletes both the version object in the VOB database along with associated metadata and the corresponding data container in a source storage pool.

There is always a `rmelem` involved (not for the version itself) but other metadata elements associated to the version that need to be removed.

If you *really* needs to remove that version, you might consider disabling temporarily the trigger, following "[How to disable a trigger in a VOB or determine if an existing trigger is already disabled](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-disable-trigger-vob-or-determine-if-existing-trigger-already-disabled)".
Something like:

```
cleartool lock -obsolete trtype:<trigger type name>
```